# how to set @Template value at run time conditionally in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I am using @Template annotation as I am using same controller for HTML and REST. Now in case of HTML, I want to render different templates in different conditions. Is there any way to set this value pragmatically ?

I can't use $this->render() because it will render template in case of REST request as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably invoke the template guesser directly, although it is probably less nice than you'd hope for. You can probably refactor a bit.

```
$guesser = $this->container->get('sensio_framework_extra.view.guesser');
if($condition) {
    $template = $guesser->guessTemplateName(array($this, 'oneAction'), $request, 'twig');
} else {
    $template = $guesser->guessTemplateName(array($this, 'twoAction'), $request, 'twig');
}
return $this->renderResponse($template, array());
```

It's not doing very much. It just uses the request format to try to guess the file name, but you can probably write something neater yourself.